# How to show appointments in org-agenda in Org v.8?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, todo, upgrade

This entry was showing alright in org-agenda in Org 7.8, if I remember correctly.

```
** Dinner
<2016-02-26 Fri 12:00-13:30>
```

Not any more in Org 8.2.
Now, it seems I need to have it this way to show up in org-agenda:

```
** TODO Dinner
<2016-02-26 Fri 12:00-13:30>
```

How could I show appointments (items without a TODO keyword) in new versions of org-agenda?

Comment: This works for me without the TODO in Org 8.3.2.  Maybe this is a bug that was introduced between 7.8 and 8.2, but fixed for 8.3?

Comment: This behavior appears to be happening when either `org-agenda-max-todos` or `org-agenda-max-entries` option is set. Again, it was fine with these options in Org 7.8. BTW, besides the appointments, this bug causes the Time Grid to disappear too.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug (or a feature) in Org 8.2.

Removing `org-agenda-max-todos` *and* `org-agenda-max-entries` options fixes it, restoring display of appointments *and* the time grid.